# Reading a file AND printing the number of words

Tags: python, file

I have to write a code that reads a file and counts the number of words in the file.

So far I am able to either print the file or count the number of numbers but I am unable to print them both without the other one automatically cancelling out.
My file:

```
This is a files
that
has different
lengths of lines
```

My code:

```py
file = open('file_lab.txt', 'rt')
print(file.read())

data = file.read()
words = data.split()

print('Number of words in text file:', len(words))
```

My output:

```
This is a files
that
has different
lengths of lines
Number of words in text file: 0
```

As you can see it prints out the word count as zero and if I were to take out "print(file.read())" it reads the number of words correctly but doesn't print out the file.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `.read()` it moves the read marker to the end of the file so when you call `.read()` again, you're already at the end.

Replace

```
print(file.read())
data = file.read()
```

with

```
data = file.read()
print(data)
```

So you're only reading the file once.

Comment: Omg that makes so much sense thank you.